# Clamp the canvas to sphere

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

I have got a sphere that moves in the world space with respect to the camera. I'm clamping an image to the sphere so that it moves together with the sphere. I'm using the following code to do so. This is attached to the sphere gameobject.

```
 public class ClampImage : MonoBehaviour
 {

     public Camera FirstpersonCamera;
     public GameObject image;

     void Update()
     {
        //get the position of the sphere in the worldspace
        Vector3 spherePosition = FirstpersonCamera.WorldToScreenPoint(this.transform.position);
        //assign the world position of the sphere to the image
        image.transform.position = spherePosition;

      }
  }
```

I tried to use the same code to clamp the Canvas itself to the sphere but it is not being clamped to the sphere. How do I clamp the entire canvas to the sphere?

**Update:**

entire canvas refers to the canvas together with its child Gameobjects like texts and images.

The canvas is within the PlayerGameobject. The following are the settings for the canvas and the player Gameobject.

**Canvas setting:**

[image: Canvas]

**Player Gameobject setting:**

[image: Player]

I have registered the player in place of the image. It just vanishes completely when I ran the code.

Comment: define "entire canvas" if you want to move the canvas, the game object youve called image could just be the canvas

Comment: `entire canvas` refers tio the canvas together with its child gameobjects like texts and images.

Comment: as I said, while you called a game object image, you can assign the canvas to that

Comment: I tried to do so but the image does not move when I do so. The canvas is in screen space with rect transform.

Comment: then put the objects in a game object and dont try moving the canvas but all the things in that object#

Comment: I have tried creating an empty gameobject. I have grouped the canvas under the empty game object. I registered the gameobject in place of map. unfortunately, it is not moving still! :(

Comment: are you resizing the canvas at all? what settings are on your canvas.. Why not just move the UI objects as a group

Comment: I have resized the canvas. Please read the updated question with the images regarding the settings

Comment: Could you please tell me how do I move the UI objects as a group?

Comment: Put them in a panel, and move the panel

Comment: If you could please post that as an answer, I will accept it... it worked like a charm. Been trying this for months. you are a legend man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you group the UI items you want in a panel, you can move the panel by placing it in your "image" variable as thats a GameObject, and then you can move the panel as required and all objects will move with it